# SSRS BIDS 2008 Bubble chart - bubble legend size

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids, bubble-chart

[image]

Does anyone know how to make the bubble chart **legend** (pictured) bigger?

Not the text, but the actual bubble's that are so small you can barely see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this out now - Right click on a bubble on the bubble chart>Series properties>Markers>

Once here adjust the 'Marker Size' using the up or down buttons, it ranges from 0-100 but for some reason once you get to around 7 or 8 the bubble in the legend will not grow any bigger.